# Simple Jquery Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(function(){
    var lr-lineheight = $('#sub').height();
    $("#lefty,#righty").css({"line-height":lr-lineheight+'px'});
)}
```

So I'm not really sure what im doing wrong here, but I'm on a deadline and would like a bit of help. Please give some input.

Comment: why are you wrapping the function into $() ???

Comment: height() & lineHeight are different things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables cannot be declared with a dash in them.

You can use underscores to split variables:

```
var my_variable = 1;
```

or you can use camel case:

```
var myVariable = 1;
```

Comment: To elaborate, most people use camel case `var lrLineheight = ....` or underscores `var lr_lineheight = ....`

Comment: @DelightedD0D I was actually editing my answer and my PC froze.

Comment: I changed the code to the following and im still not getting the result i want. Im trying to change the lineheight of #right and #lefty to be the same as the height of #sub          $(function(){
 var lrlineheight = $('#sub').height();
 $("#lefty,#righty").css({"line-height":lrlineheight+'px',"height":lrlineheight+'px'});
)}

Comment: @DelightedD0D how's that now?

Comment: @JRobz You seem to have some goober'd-up characters in that code, see http://i.imgur.com/PiB1xV5.png , Ive seen that happen before when I copy text from my windows instance running in VMWare and paste  it into my a program on my Mac

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks for the +1. *It froze again...*

Comment: @DelightedD0D how can i remove those characters if they arn't being displayed in my text-editor. Could that be the issue with the code?

Comment: Figured it out lol. At the end of my code i had )} instead of }); Thanks for you're help guys

Comment: @JRobz glad I could help.

Comment: Any reason why the value of the variable is 100 off from the actual value